# How does modularization technically solve callback hell in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

When researching 'callback hell' in nodejs, I get a lot of sites that recommend the same things.  Shallow functions, modularization, and then some tools like promises, async, and generators.

I technically know what callbacks are, and I know why they're used in nodejs. I understand the value of modularizing your code.

I don't understand how modularization actually solves callback hell?

In the end aren't you just still calling functions that have callbacks?

Comment: *"I don't understand how modularization actually solves callback hell?"* - I am not sure that it does. (Though modularisation is helpful to keep a codebase tidy regardless of whether you need to use callbacks or not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how modularization actually solves callback hell?

It does not solve callback hell.

A module essentially lets you split up a program on as many files as you want. The program could also just be in a single file (disregarding the unrelated benefits of using modules).

> In the end aren't you just still calling functions that have callbacks?

Yes.

You can however use certain coding patterns to avoid callback hell. But using modules is not going to solve anything whether or not you use a traditional callback pattern.